# How to modify pre built approver status (Request Change)

Tags: sharepoint-designer

Hello im new to sharepoint, i want to modify my Request Change workflow, but i cant find the workflow of this part, can anybody enlighten me about this Request change workflow? thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The Request change only shows up if this option is selected in the settings of the task form. This is also where you will be able to modify the tasks. Right above that you will see customizations. Change the overall behavior of the task and you will be able to modify this. If you wish to change the button, then open the xsn file and modify it in InfoPath.

To get to the task page. Edit workflow. Select text in workflow for the task and the page comes up.

To get to the InfoPath form. Go to workflow settings and at the lower right you will see the xsn file. First have InfoPath, then open it up. Select the button. edit properties, change the title.